# Why is this simple C program not showing any output?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, printf

I have to count how many times the loop runs for a given input, I am trying to use a custom value for `n` to come up with a formula but the following dummy program does not show any output nor does it show any error. There are custom values of `n` which vary as `4^k` and I have used a random value `64` to see how many times the loop runs.

I have tried to include the `printf()` statement in the while loop itself to see if the compiler even enters that loop or not but I still am not getting any result. I haven't done much programming in C and I am running the program in an online compiler.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;

    int n=64;
    int count=0;
    
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        j = 2;
        while(j<=n){
            j = i*i;
            count +=1 ;
            
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d",count);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may not be a long enough string to fill the buffer. Try adding a newline:`printf("%d\n",count);`.

Comment: Please do not mix different bracket styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First loop, going into the `while` loop. We assign

```
j = 2
```

Then, while `j` is less than 64, we assign

```
j = 1 * 1
```

Now we reset the while loop, but `i` is unchanged, so we do again

```
j = 1 * 1
```

So this is an infinite while loop that never completes.